# External hiperlink to shiny tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with several tabPanel within a navbarPage. I am trying to link a particular tabPanel to send this url to someone. Is that possible? I found in the web browser something like /#tab-1284-4 that refers to this tabPanel but, may I assign a name to it in order to use it as the url?